# Renaming and merging columns based on an old/new name dataset

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

A confusing title.

Best explained by an example.

I have the following data

```
df     <- "Green.Apple  Red.Apple Pears  Orange  Lemon  Lime
1               3           5       4      4       0     5
2               3           0       2      7       2     11
3               2           7       8      0       3     1
4               0           6       3      5       6     0 "

df    <-read.table(text=df,header=T)
```

I would like to rename the columns based on an old / new names, and then merge those columns based on the old and new names. If a column being renamed is also the same as another column they would be summed. I bring the names into the workspace:

```
names  <- "Original     New
1         Green.Apple  Apple
2         Red.Apple    Apple
3         Pears        Pear
4         Orange       Orange
5         Lemon        Cirtus
6         Lime         Cirtus"
#

names <-read.table(text=names,header=T)
```

I have tried various work around methods. e.g. they will always have the same length of names so one could simply rename the columns by a list, but this is not proper and could result in errors in the larger task I am trying to accomplish.

This is what I am looking for:

```
yay <- "Apple   Pear  Orange  Cirtus
1         8       4     4       5
2         3       2     7       13
3         9       8     0       4
4         6       3     5       6"
```

Many thanks

Jim
(controversial: Also open to a Pandas alternative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `match` to match old names with new names and rename `df`. Then use `split.default` to split based on similar names and sum similar columns.

```
names(df) <- names$New[match(names(df), names$Original)]
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), rowSums)

#  Apple Cirtus Orange Pear
#1     8      5      4    4
#2     3     13      7    2
#3     9      4      0    8
#4     6      6      5    3
```

Comment: damn I stupidly forgot to include in my example a number of metadata columns that come before the fruits, anyway to ignore a column if it does not appear in the original names. Easy fix?

Comment: @Jim Do you know how many columns are there before actual columns you are interested in? You could just remove/select some columns. `df[3:9]` to select 3-9 columns or `df[-(1:2)]` to remove first two columns. Would it help?

Comment: Yes, that will be my solution as the meta is consistent in length so easy to incorporate into the function, thank you. I was thinking an `if(exists` type deal.

Comment: yes, that could be done too. The names which are not present in `names` dataset would return `NA`, then you have to filter those and select only those column which are not `NA`.

Comment: Awesome, cheers for your (consistent) help, you have answered 4 of my questions are seriously helping my PhD. So thank you so much! and thanks SO.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do:

```
names(df) <- names$New[match(names(df), names$Original)]
t(rowsum(t(df), group = colnames(df), na.rm = T))

# > t(rowsum(t(df), group = colnames(df), na.rm = T))
# Apple Cirtus Orange Pear
# 1     8      5      4    4
# 2     3     13      7    2
# 3     9      4      0    8
# 4     6      6      5    3
```

Comment: This works, but is similar to the 'work around', thank you